# Captcha Implementation in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, captcha, recaptcha

Do I need to create a database table to implement captcha on a registration form?

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using [reCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/) rather than implementing your own system? There is a [Ruby library](http://svn.ambethia.com/pub/rails/plugins/recaptcha/) available although I haven't personally used it.

Comment: Even if I use recaptcha or any other third party plugin, do I need a table to match the captcha code with what the user enters as an answer?

Comment: With recaptcha, you don't. see http://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/1b8c52017467a1ae19397320615b63387cef03ba/README.rdoc